# Accessing server controls from different pages

Tags: asp.net

I have a `GridView` on `PageA`, I wish to be able to call the `DataBind()` method of the GridView from `PageB`?

Basically `PageB` is a form which will be contained in a pop up control, when the user fills in the fields of the form on `PageB` and submits it I will close the pop up control, then I want to refresh the `GridView` on the parent page (PageA), how would I go about doing that?

Comment: you can do that using javascript.

Comment: An idea: Convert PageB into a UserControl. Create an event on PageB say `FormSubmit`, now after user submits in PageB, handle that event and raise `FormSubmit`. Now, from PageA add a event handler for `FormSubmit` and call databind

Comment: @Aristos, I already did that, I had a method that I called which re-binded the gridview on the parent page, but the gridview w  snot being refreshed, my guess is that since I was calling the method with the client side click event of the save button, the gridview was being refreshed BEFORE my data was actually submitted to the database...

Comment: So what's your plan for concurrency; can the GridView be edited from anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Write a javascript function on Page A like RefreshGrid, you can write various ways to refresh grid from this javascript function e.g.

1) put your grid inside an update panel and create a trigger button control on that update panel , call this trigger control's click event in javascript , this will partial post back the page and refresh the update panel. There are other ways too..

2) From popup on popup close button, write following line

```
window.opener.RefreshGrid(); window.close();
```

Thats it.

If you want to pass any parameter you can pass through as argument to RefreshGrid function.

Still there are many ways , this is the one I use.